# How to add input tags by clicking from instant search in html (AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs, selection

I'm a newbie in Angular JS and trying to add input tags by clicking from instant search using Angular JS.

I found the example of [instant search](https://www.trycatchclasses.com/angularjs-instant-search-example/) [demo](https://www.trycatchclasses.com/code/demo/angular-instant-search/index.html) from Google, and from the link I want to make input tags by clicking from instant search bar.

How do I make it like below figure?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
[<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Person Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" placeholder="Search Name...">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="listdata in names|filter:search">
        <td>{{listdata.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

var c=angular.module('myApp',[]);

c.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){

    $scope.names = [
    {name: 'Krishnaiah'},
     {name: 'Ramana'},
      {name: 'ALex'},
       {name: 'Remo'},
        {name: 'Alena'},
    ]
})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/5Tb4aaHQn2eim3caTLyE?p=preview